# Silverlight got http302 error after login successfully in iframe

Tags: silverlight, iframe, http-status-code-302

I have one silverlight 4 application which contains one iframe to show aspx pages. The silverlight app and the application in iframe, both are hosted in the same web server.

First, there are two login.aspx pages. One is in silverlight app, other is in another site which is embedded in iframe. My silverlight app will be loaded first and login successfully for silverlight app.

Then, in my silverlight app, there is one link button to load the aspx page into iframe.

When I access the aspx page in the iframe at the first tim, it will go to its login.aspx and login successfully. After that, I go back to the silverlight app, i immediately get the http 302 error. But the duration between i access aspx page and the silvelight app, not bigger than the time of session timeout.

So could anyone be able to figure out what can make the error?

P.S. It only occures after aspx page logins successfully. If I do not touch the aspx pages in iframe, just acces the silverlight pages, it will have no error.

Answer (score 0):

Today  found the root cause and resolved it. It is due to the two applications are placed into same machine. Then, the second login will overwrote the authentication cookie of the first login.  (It meant to call the sencond's FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() will overwrite the first ones.) So the solution is very easy. Just to make their authentication cookie name different:

`

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".SecondAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx"
    defaultUrl="default.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

`